# Rotate positions of elements in array every second in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to create a loop in JS that is every second changing / rotating positions of N elements in array in a way that first becomes second, second becomes third, and so on, last becomes first and when is over repeat it again

first step

```
array = ['1','2','3'];
```

second step

```
array = ['2','3','1'];
```

third step

```
array = ['3','1','2'];
```

repeat

it seems quite easy but I'm stuck

thanks

Comment: Actually your text is different from your example. The text says **last becomes first** in your example the last element becomes second

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Array.shift()` will remove the first element. `Array.push()` will add the element at the end

`setInterval` will execute the function every `1000` ms

```js
let array = [1,2,3];

setInterval(()=>{
  array.push(array.shift());     
  console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

very simple

```js
//ES5
var array = ['1','2','3'];

function rotate(){
  setInterval(function(){
    console.log(array);
    array.push(array.shift())        
  },1000)  
}

rotate();
```

Comment: you should mention how. also give credit to the comment on question by Jonas (which deleted later)